# How can I make a query retrieving highest rated movie?

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following tables:

```
Movie ( mID, title, year, director ) 

Reviewer ( rID, name ) 

Rating ( rID, mID, stars, ratingDate )
```

What i want to do is get the directors name along with the movies name which he has directed and got the highest rating.

For example, if Steven Spielberg has directed two movies (namely `A` and `B`) which have got 3 stars and 5 stars rating respectively, then the query must show Steven Spielberg and B (movie with the highest rating).

PS: I only need help with the approach. Hope I made myself clear. Please ask if any more info or explanation needed.

Comment: find the movies directed by Steven Spielberg, order by rating in descending order, limit results to 1.

Comment: how do i limit the results??

Comment: You should [edit your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17485673/edit) to make it conform with the site's requirements, rather than posting a new one.

Comment: Highest *overall* rating or highest rating from a single review? From a five star rating system, a large proportion of movies are likely to end up with at least one five-star rating.

Comment: in `mysql` - `LIMIT 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a subselect to get the director and the highest rating:-

```
SELECT director, MAX(stars)
FROM Movie
INNER JOIN Rating
ON Movie.mID = Rating.mID
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT director, MAX(stars) AS MaxRating
    FROM Movie
    INNER JOIN Rating
    ON Movie.mID = Rating.mID
    GROUP BY director
) Sub1
ON Movie.directort = Sub1.director
AND Rating.stars = Sub1.MaxRating
```

However I presume you will need more details. You do not appear to use the reviewer table at the moment, and I presume that one movie could have had several different reviewers who could have given different ratings. If so you would want to use the above as a subselect to join back against the rating table (macthign on the title and stars), and from that to the reviewer table.

Comment: this is very close but there is one small problem...steven spielberg has directed two movies one wid rating 3 and the other wid 4..it shud show only the rating 4 but it is showing both the ratings...oderwise it works fine for all other directors..

Comment: Fixed. But there are loads of extra bits you need to specify. For example, what happens if 2 movies by the same directory have the same rating? Do you want to return just one of them (in which case which one), both of them on a single row, or 2 rows, one for each movie (which is what the above will currently do)

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try this,

```
SELECT TITLE,DIRECTOR FROM MOVIE,
(SELECT MAX(STARS),mID FROM RATING GROUP BY mID) R
WHERE MOVIE.mID=R.mID
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
SELECT q.* FROM (SELECT m.*,MAX(r.`stars`) AS maxrating FROM `movie` m 
INNER JOIN `rating` r ON (m.`mID` = r.`mID` ) 
GROUP BY r.`mID` ORDER BY maxrating DESC ) q GROUP BY q.director 
ORDER BY q.maxrating DESC
```

And i am sure this question is taken from the [**quiz of DB class provided by stanford university**](http://class2go.stanford.edu/db/Winter2013/interactive_exercises/SQLMovie-RatingQueryExercisescoreset)

[**Here is your fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b9c64/2)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do that is:

```
select m.title, max(r.stars) as stars
from rating r
inner join movie m on r.mid = m.mid
group by r.mid
order by m.title
```

Answer (score -1):

this code should suffice :

```
select distinct m1.director, m1.title, r1.stars from movie m1
join rating r1 on m1.mID = r1.mID
left join (
    select m2.director, r2.stars from movie m2
    join rating r2 on m2.mID = r2.mID
) s on m1.director = s.director and r1.stars < s.stars
where s.stars is null and m1.director is not null;
```

Comment: just leave from here...u r of no use here..this code is bullshit

Comment: Explanation of code (or some comments) would help others more